# Google Maps will not display Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API v=3 (was using v=2, same problem). I have tried latest Chrome, latest Firefox, latest IE11. I am able to display a map and pan to a new center, but I cannot get a Marker to display. Here are script headers:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
<!-- Load Google Maps Javascript API -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3"
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

And when user clicks on a particular location in a table, the following function is invoked. There is a map on the page, and the map pans to the new location, but the Marker never appears.

```
function setMapCenter(map, latitude, longitude)
{
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng( latitude, longitude );
    map.panTo(center);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: center,map: map,title: 'HERE'});
}
```

Does anyone see a problem here? Thanks.

I have made a pretty simple page that exhibits the problem. Load the page, click on any of the lat-long links and see the map pan to new location - but no marker is displayed. Here it is: http://www.glenn-nelson.us/marker.html

Comment: Any errors? Are you passing in `map`, `lat` and `lng` in properly?

Comment: when `map.panTo(center)` works there shouldn't be any problem, can you give us a demo of the issue or more code?

Comment: Nothing in the code posted explains the issue, need more context, can you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem?  Or can you provide a jsfiddle or a link to your map that exhibits the problem?  You might want to look at the documentation and update you include of the API script, the way you are doing it is outdated, but should work.

Comment: If your `latitude` and `longitude` are strings than you have to use `parseFloat()` method. Otherwise check your `map` variable.

Comment: Since map.panTo works, I assume that 'map' and 'center' are valid. What is wrong with my include of the API? I will make a simplified page and also a JSfiddle to share. Thanks for comments.

Comment: I've added a link in the question that demonstrates the problem. The page source is simple.

Comment: @geocodezip I finally returned to this problem and discovered you were correct. But I sure wish you had told me where to look for the new and improved API.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is both an updated Google Maps API specification and a different syntax for initial map creation. My sample link has been updated to show the working version.

***GOOD:***

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
      type="text/javascript">
</script>

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -122.0000);
    mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"),
                 {zoom: 11,
                  center: center,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: center,map: mymap,title: 'HERE'});
}
```

Here's the ***BAD*** code I started with:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -122.0000);
    mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"));
    mymap.setCenter(center, 11);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: center,map: mymap,title: 'HERE'});
}
```

Although this could generate a map and calls to map.setCenter() or map.panTo() would work, it was unable to display any markers. Furthermore, when I changed the API script to the new format "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", my map DIV then went solid gray. And new API script format with the old initialize function also  gave me gray.

So, old API designation with older map construction is OK, but markers simply don't display.
New API designation with new map construction also allows me to see markers.